# Controlling the gap between cells in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

My cells seem to have a gap of about 20 points, I want to control that value, but every answer I found regarding this question does not work.

I tried:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}
```

without any useful output, also:

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
```

and these two lines also didn't help.

Please note that I'm not using the storyboard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically speaking, the gap value should be based on *what's the cell size*, editing the minimum spaces leads to how the row should be displayed. To make it more clear, consider the following scenario:

it's required to display 2 cells for each row, each cell's width should be half of the screen width, if the minimum spaces have been set to zeros, the output will be: both cells should fill the screen width.

So far so good, *but* what if the cell's width should be more than half of the screen width (let's consider that it should be half of the width + 2 points)? the output will be: each row will contain only 1 cell, besides it a gap with the width of the half of screen - 2 points.

So, the **solution** is to *make sure* to set the appropriate size for the cells, by implementing [collection​View:​layout:​size​For​Item​At​Index​Path:​](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview?language=objc) correctly. You might want to check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957826/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-a-2x2-uicollectionview-and-fit-the-whole-screen-swi/39958163#39958163) to know how you can achieve it.

Comment: @DownVoter please comment your reason down voting the answer, it seems that you are doing that sarcastically for all given answers with no reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionat section: Int) -> CGFloat {
print("collectionView===\(collectionView)")
print("collectionViewLayout===\(collectionViewLayout)")
print("section===\(Int(section))")
return 10.0
}
```

**Line spacing**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionat section: Int) -> CGFloat {
print("collectionView===\(collectionView)")
print("collectionViewLayout===\(collectionViewLayout)")
print("section===\(Int(section))")
return 10.0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionat section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
print("collectionView===\(collectionView)")
print("collectionViewLayout===\(collectionViewLayout)")
print("section===\(Int(section))")
// return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20)
// top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change thus values In properties of uicollection view.. as seen below..

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention I'm not using the storyboard.