# Make a array of type CGFloat which has multiple values inside of it

Tags: ios, swift

This is my code:

```
var array = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Xcode thinks its a double array. It should be a CGFloat array. I already tried

```
var array: CGFloat = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
var array = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)] as! CGFloat
var array: [CGFloat] = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

and some other options without success. How to let Xcode know this is an CGFloat array? I can not append values to the array now.

Comment: Not sure what you need parentheses for. Isn't `let array: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` working?

Comment: Actually, what are you declaring is an array of *tuples*. I posted an answer  for describing what's going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, There are some points that you should consider:

- `var array = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]` is *not* an array of Doubles, it is an array of *tuples* which contain four Doubles, i.e if you tried to <kbd>cmd</kbd> and click at `array`, you will see that its data type as: `[(Double, Double, Double, Double)]`.

Adapted from [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html):

> Tuples group multiple values into a single compound value. The values
>   within a tuple can be of any type and do not have to be of the same
>   type as each other.

- If you are *pretty sure* about making it as an array of tuples, but you cannot let it as array of tuples of CGFloats, it should be:
  `var array: [(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)] = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]`

  its data type will be `[(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)]`.
- If your purpose to let be an array of CGFloats, then there is no need to add `()` when declaring it:
  `let array: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

  Note that when assigning a floating-point number to a variable, it should be of type `Double`, so you have to give the desired data type (which is in your case is `[CGFloat]`).

Hope this helped.

Comment: Funny how this is the only answer which answers my answer and has no up votes. Thank you for your time! This worked, unlike the others.

Comment: Glad to help :) ya, sometimes it kind seems like kind of weird! need something funnier? [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229758/controlling-the-gap-between-cells-in-uicollectionviewcontroller/43230086#43230086) is the the right one and I got 2 downvotes for it :D if you have time, you can check it to make sure that its ok, really dope!

Answer (score 3):

The correct and easy way to initialize Swift array with literal:

```
let array: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Or if you really want to initialize it with repeated values:

```
let array = [CGFloat](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is an array of tuples! Drop the `()` and you're good.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

// What you want, an array of type [CGFloat]
let rightArray: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

// What you have, an array of type [(Double, Double, Double, Double)] (an array of tuples that contain 4 doubles)
let wrongArray = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll be good if you use
`var array: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`